# How to apply different functions to the respective items in a dask bag, similar to bag.to_textfiles(_, name_function)

Tags: python, dask

### Core Problem

So in dask you can do

```py
import dask.bag as db

bag = db.from_sequence([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
# Save with file names "name_function(i), where i is incremented.
bag.to_textfiles(path, name_function)
```

where a slightly different function, namely the `name_function` with different index,
is applied to the saving operation of each item in the bag.
Is there a way do something similar with a mapping on a bag?

```py
def get_fct(i):
"""Return function that multiplies input by `i`."""
    return lambda x, n=i: x * n
get_fct(6)(7)  # 42

bag.map(func_func=get_fct).compute()  # [0, 2, 6, 12, 20].
```

Of course the result would not be deterministic due to the fact that a bag is not ordered, but this is fine.

### Context

In my project I'd like to do something akin to  `db.to_textfiles()`, but with a different saving function, not saving strings to textfiles. For example:

```py
from functools import partial

import numpy as np

def get_save_fct(path: str, i: int) -> Callable[[np.ndarray], None]:
    """Return a function that takes an array as input and saves it at 'path/i.npy'"""
    file = f"{path}/{i}.npy"
    return partial(np.save, file=file)


bag = db.from_delayed([np.array([i]) for i in range 5])
# Save numpy arrays under different file names in the same directory.
bag.map(func_func=partial(get_save_fct, "/foo/bar").compute()
# Only argument "i" is left unapplied to the save function.
```

where `partial(get_save_fct, "/foo/bar")` takes "i" as an input to return a function that saves a respective bag item at "/foo/bar/i.npy". How could I make something like this work? (Do I need to touch dask actors to construct a counter to tackle this problem? Seems overblown, regarding that `db.to_textfiles` exists already).

Thank you to your help!

Comment: Can you step back a bit and explain what you’re trying to do? I’m wondering if there’s a way around this “creating bags of writer functions” idea

Comment: note that `to_textfiles` does _not_ create pre-populated functions with the same length as the number of bags. instead, you provide a callable which is executed once within each task called on each bag to generate the output filename. the difference is that the number of defined functions is 1 in the `to_textfiles` case, even though it's called nbags times, where as you're trying to define nbags functions. Could you get around this by just providing two args on save, e.g. `bag.map(custom_save_func, i=dask.bag.Bag(range(bag.count().compute()))`, with `custom_save_func(item, i)`?

Comment: I was unaware of the fact that you could pass a `Bag` as argument to the `db.map` in order to achieve different keyword arguments for the respective function calls of the items of the original bag. That solves my problem indeed (reading the docs of the map method helped, too). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to Michael Delgado's comments I can now present a solution for the core problem, as well as the more concrete problem.

### Core Answer

I will give a minimal example for how to apply a set of different functions to the elements of a `Bag` object:

```py
from math import ceil, floor  # example functions

import dask.bag as db


bag = db.from_sequence([0.1, 0.2, 0.9])
functions = [round, ceil, floor]

# Indices for selecting the functions.
idx_bag = db.from_sequence(range(bag.count().compute()))

bag.map(
    func=lambda v, i: functions[i](v),
    i=idx_bag
).compute()  # [0, 1, 0]
```

By setting `i=idx_bag`, the `i` argument to the lambda function is pre-applied. Thus, the function being applied to the bag item only depends on `v`.

From the examples in the [API docs of `dask.bag.map`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.bag.map.html#dask.bag.map) it is apparent that *Bag* arguments will *not* be broadcasted across all calls to `func`. The items of arguments bags are broadcasted to one `func` call at a time. This allows for different behavior of `func` regarding the items of the target `bag`.

### Context Answer

So how to use this property of *Bag* arguments in our favor? How to save a number of items under different file names? Let's get bag to the numpy example:

```py
import dask.bag as db
import numpy as np

bag = db.from_delayed([np.array([i]) for i in range 5])

# Save arrays under different file names in the same directory.
files = db.from_sequence(
    ["/foo/bar/{i}.npy" for i in range(bag.count().compute())]
)
bag.map(
    func=np.save,
    file=files
).compute()
```

The items of the `files` Bag will be broadcasted to the calls to `func` one at a time. Thus, The numpy arrays will be saved under different file names.

Comment: Nice! Glad this worked and thanks for taking the time to turn this into an answer!